# Show that a group can not be expressed as union of two of its proper subgroups

Tags: group-theory

Show that a group can not be expressed as union of two of its proper subgroups. I am not sure how to start.

Comment: You might want to check also this [entry][1]


  [1]: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/36698/applications-of-the-fact-that-a-group-is-never-the-union-of-two-of-its-proper-su

Answer (score 17):

HINT: Suppose that $H,K<G$, and let $h\in H\setminus K$ and $k\in K\setminus H$; where is $hk$?

Comment: I was just about to ask how to continue and I got it :) (+1)